# Parashat Hashavu'a Chat - Trial

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, events

You are invited to our first ever

### Parashat Hashavu'a Chat

- **Where**: The Judaism.SE [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning)
- **When**: Wednesday, December 7, 2011 17:30 UTC (19:30 in Israel; 12:30
  EST)

  (You can get a doodad for your calendar [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=schedule) if you're into that sort of thing.)
- **What**: Freewheeling conversation related to this week's [Torah
  Portion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Torah_portion): [Vayishlach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayishlach)
- **Why**: People like to talk about the Parasha.

This is a trial. If it goes well, we can make it a regular thing. Feel free to suggest changes in timing, format, etc., here.

---

UPDATE:

[Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/parashat-hashavua-chat-1-vayishlach-5772)'s the transcript of the chat. I think it was a success and would be worth repeating. I'd love to hear feedback from anyone who was there or even anyone who reads the transcript on whether, how, and when we should do this next: please post answers here.

Comment: My brain keeps reading the title of this post as "פרשת השבוע חט", not that חט means anything, to my knowledge.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/520/2 : We'll be repeating this every week until further notice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly be interested in participating in the next one - it looks like it was quite an interesting conversation.

Comment: We had another one today. Until further notice, we'll do them every Wednesday. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/520/2

Comment: Whoops, I totally forgot yesterday!  Setting a calendar reminder now for next week... would it be worth a banner next Wednesday since this is new, or are we relying on meta for a reminder?

Comment: @MonicaCellio it turns out that we're not supposed to use banners for non-emergency purposes. The site auto-generates a small banner while the event is happening, and I might create a "warm-up" event in part to allow for some advance warning. Also, you can go [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=schedule) and register, and you'll get various kinds of auto-reminders.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, thanks for the explanation (and link to register).  I knew they didn't want us to use banners for the weekly challenge, but I didn't realize the relevant factor was "emergency".

Comment: @MonicaCellio, that's not a precise definition, but generally speaking, the community moderators (msh210, WAF, and I) will not be posting such banners anymore.